# Possible to copy/duplicate a CCLayer?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm creating a scene that will have a list of items, like a shop menu. Ideally, I want to create the layout for a single shop item in CocosBuilder. Then, in code, I access that layout and make multiple copies for all my shop items, which can be added to the scene.

Is this possible in cocos2d-x?

Comment: I think just creating this layer multiple times and adding them to scene will work.

Comment: You can create a layer and add it with different tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all of items you have are CCSprite, you can use this code for duplicating it:

```
CCSprite* copy=CCSprite::spriteWithTexture(source->getTexture());
```

you can duplicate all sprites in a layer then add them to a new layer.